# How do I change foreground color based on which command line program is running? (Bash and PowerShell)

Tags: bash, powershell, colors

I'd like to change the foreground color based on which program is running. Is this possible in either Bash or PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell you can use the Write-Host cmdlet which has the -ForeGround parameter to control the foreground for the text. Be aware though that text written to the console via this cmdlet does **not** go to the pipeline which can lead to some unexpected behavior if you expect to work with the text later in the pipe.

Here is an example:

```
(get-help write-host).Description.Text | write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can define a bunch of functions:

```
function command_name
{
    trap ':' 2
    command to set desired color(s)
    full_path_to_command "$@"
    command to restore default color(s)
}
```

for each command/program you want to have in a different color.  For example,

```
function date
{
    trap ':' 2
    echo "\033[31m\c"
    /bin/date "$@"
    echo "\033[30m\c"
}
```

The `trap` command causes the function to keep on running if you interrupt the program (by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).  Without it, if you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while your colored program is running, your terminal will be left in the color for that command.  (There may be better ways to handle this.)

`"$@"` is replaced by the arguments you type to the function, so if you say `date -u`, it knows to pass the `-u` option to the `/bin/date` command.

You might want to define a function that does nothing but restore your default color(s).  Since that doesn't need to take arguments, it can be done as an `alias`.